# Firebase shell still reads my Node version 12 instead of the Nvm version

Tags: node.js, firebase, nvm, firebase-cli

My problem is a bit tedious and need the community to help me out here. 
I installed node 12 from the official site of `Nodejs.org` using it's `.pkg` file. 
I use firebase functions shell to test our work locally, but due to version conflicts I need to downgrade to 10. 
This is where the problems start, I installed `NVM` to get the downgraded version, and I was successful, so when I do `node -v` I see the `v10` but when I run

`firebase functions:shell`

I still get the warning

`Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "12"`

Now I need to get this sorted because my local cloud functions still don't work and I think it's still reading the 12th version of the node. I've followed different tutorials of manually deleting node from your system and again I was able to delete Node by verifying

`node -v` it gave me an error of `node command not found` which means Node was deleted, but even though Node uninstalled I still was able to run

`firebase functions:shell` and run the cloud function locally, so it means node 12 is still in the system but I can't seem to uninstall it.

So any help in this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following ways

1. Delete firebase from the global directory in the root folder. 
   So I wrote `which firebase` and it gave me a location on the root folder. I deleted that firebase instance.
2. Then I installed firebase using `npm i -g firebase-tools` this was installed directly into my `nvm` version of the node.

Only after that I was able to run `firebase` on the node version which I was using on the `nvm`

Comment: This helped me as well. I had a fresh install where I used the firebase cURL installation instructions. Switching to npm made it work properly.

Comment: for me just reinstalling firebase-tools with `npm i -g firebase-tools` fixed the issue. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Running `nvm use 14` (or whatever version you want) helped solve things for me in addition to reinstalling firebase tools

Answer (score 1):

Open a new terminal and use nvm to set the version you need `npm use 12`. Finally, install the packages again with `npm install`.