# "node" version "14" doesn't match your global version "12" when running node 16 in WSL

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I'm using node 16 inside WSL (somehow that's the only way firebase works w my pc)

anyways - I'm trying to use a top level await in my code and I get an error indicating the await's placement in addition to the following:

```
⚠  Your requested "node" version "14" doesn't match your global version "12". Using node@12 from host.
```

I've used n as a version manager inside WSL and NVM for my windows 10 system. Both version 16.

I tried two solutions:

```
sudo n use 14
sudo n use 16
```

sadly - nothing happened.
I've updated the version every time in the packgage.json and yet - nothing.

I think it's important to note that I'm using Firebase functions - it can probably indicate another issue

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: this answer solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315185/firebase-shell-still-reads-my-node-version-12-instead-of-the-nvm-version

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you have a problem with Firbase-tools.
When installing Firbase-tools via the binary, it is installed with version 12 of Node.

**I solved the problem by reinstalling Firbase-tools via npm.**

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```